# inside visual studio there is no files for ios in cross plate forms. error displaying (incompatible)

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

Please help me
i have installed Xamarin in visual studio 2015 community. But when i want to work in cross plate forms it displays error "Ios failed" and in solution explorer there is message with ios files (ios incompatible)
please help me how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Visual Studio and iOS but no Mac I guess you problem is the Mac.

If you want to make an iOS App in Visual Studio and Xamarin forms you will need a Mac. Visual Studio will use it as a Xamarin Mac Agent. Visual Studio sends the "Code" to the Mac and the Mac will create the iOS App for you.

Comment: i want to make just .apk file but nothing is happening .
when i right click on android solution and Archive it then error display "ios is not installed"
even that i am working on cross plate forms so if ios is not installed then for android this is not a issue but issue is there i dont know why and how it is possible

Comment: If you don't need the iOS project have you tried removing it from your solution?

Comment: it automatically removed. there is only 1 project that is android. But when i want to Archive it . then error message appears IOS failed. when i open the project which i already made. then it says IOS is not compatible.